# Call a Web ApI method with Parameters using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am calling a web API with angularJS Service.

My webp API method is working fine without parameters `'/api/Subpart/'`

When i tried to pass parameters , Web API method is not firing.

**Angular service**

```
.service('subpartService', ['$http', function ($http) {
     this.getSubparts = function (val) {
       return $http.get('/api/Subpart/'+val); // With parameters not working
     };
 }])
```

**Web API Controller Action**

```
[Route("api/Subpart/{strsubpart}")]
public List<tbl_Employee> GetSubparts(string strsubpart)
{
    Entities db = new Entities();
    var data = db.tbl_Regulation.Where(c => c.Subsection == "ABC");
    return data.ToList();
}
```

Comment: What else have you tried. Can you call it with a parameter from your browser? Are you sure that `val` has a valid non empty/ non null / non undefined string value? Also what does `without parameters '/api/Subpart/'` mean? This is a route and not a parameter, you cant call the method without it so what do you mean it was working fine without it?

Comment: Ohh Very Strange. Its working, When i pass my api Url as 'api/Subpart/abc'

Comment: Is the angular service running on the same web site as where the web api is hosted? If not you will need to provide the complete host address as well.

Comment: actually my parameter value coming as 'api/Subpart/1301.2(b)' because of 1301.2(b) its not working

Comment: How to handle this format 1301.2(b) in api url?

Comment: try this edit: return $http.get('/api/Subpart?strsubpart='+val);

Comment: Check your error logs. Also inspect the ajax request in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: If it was me I would look for a different identifier to send...or use POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution.It has pass parameters with ?

```
this.getSubparts = function (val) {
           var subUrl = "http://localhost/api/Subpart/sub_part?subpart="+ val;
             return $http.get(subUrl);
         };
```

Comment: Hi, My web APi method is firing When i pass my parameters as http://localhost/api/Subpart/sub_part?1301.2(b)  But instead of 1301.2(b) value coming as 'sub_part' ?

Comment: why actual value is not coming in web api method?

Answer (score 0):

Try to "escape" the value.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

```
this.getSubparts = function (val) {
           var subUrl = "http://localhost/api/Subpart/?subpart="+ encodeURI(val);
             return $http.get(subUrl);
         };
```